# Remove row from SELECT based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex stored procedure that I need to be able to hide a specific row from a table joined onto the primary table. The criteria of hiding this row is based on whether a value (DeductMoney) in the primary table (Orders) is a 1. My stored procedure is similar to this:

```
SELECT 
  O.FileNumber
  ,ML.Line
  ,ML.Price
  ,ML.Description
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Main M 
  ON O.OrdersID = M.OrdersID 
INNER JOIN MainLine ML
  ON ML.MainID = M.MainID
WHERE 
  M.MainID = @MainID
```

The result set currently looks like the following:

```
FileNumber | Line | Price | Description
---------------------------------------
0001       | 501  | $200  | DescriptionA
0001       | 502  | $300  | DescriptionB
0001       | 503  | $150  | DescriptionC
0001       | 504  | $100  | DescriptionD
0001       | 505  | $75   | DescriptionE
0001       | 506  | $500  | DescriptionF
```

Now from the Orders table, there is a column named DeductMoney. This column ONLY applies to one specific row of the returned result set, Line 506. The DeductMoney column can either be a 0 or 1, and if it is a 1, I need to completely remove the row from the SQL SELECT. So essentially, if DeductMoney = 1, remove the row that Line 506 exists.

This data is unfortunately not being passed to SSRS, so I cannot filter it at that level. Does anyone have thoughts of how I would carry this out? Is it possible to do it via a CASE statement? Any help is much appreciated!

Remove row from SELECT based on column value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add logic to your `where` clause:

```
WHERE M.MainID = @MainID AND
      NOT (Line = 506 and DeductMoney = 1)
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer... but if you really need to do it with the CASE statement :
  WHERE M.MainID = @MainID AND
      CASE
          WHEN ML.Line = 506 AND DeductMoney = 1 THEN 0
          ELSE 1
      END = 1

Comment: Wow, something so simple that I completely overlooked it. Ha! Thanks for helping me with my brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work, or am I misreading something?

```
SELECT 
  O.FileNumber
  ,ML.Line
  ,ML.Price
  ,ML.Description
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Main M 
  ON O.OrdersID = M.OrdersID 
INNER JOIN MainLine ML
  ON ML.MainID = M.MainID
WHERE 
  M.MainID = @MainID
  AND DeductMoney <> 1
```

Comment: Since DeductMoney would appear on every line, it would omit all the results entirely.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood, did not know that it would be the 506 line every time.